# React-Table: Select Single Row Only, Disable Multiple Row Selection

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v6, react-table-v7

I am using radio buttons to select the rows. How do I disable multiple row selection so only one row can be selected at a time?

I am using `selectedFlatRows`, but it's allowing for multiple row selection.

```
const Table = props => {
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    page,
    prepareRow,
    selectedFlatRows,
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data: props.linkedProducts,
    },
    useSortBy,
    usePagination,
    useRowSelect,
    hooks => {
      hooks.visibleColumns.push(columns => [
        {
          id: 'selection',
          disableGlobalFilter: true,
          accessor: 'selection',
          Cell: ({row}) => (
            <RadioButton
              {...row.getToggleRowSelectedProps()}
            />
          ),
        },
        ...columns,
      ]);
    }
  );
```

Comment: Hi there, did you find a solution?
I'm currently facing the same problem

Comment: @Àtishking just posted my solution, let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 5):

I was puzzling over this one for a while, the solution I used seems to work fine and is very simple. Use the following in your onClick() method:

```
  onClick={() => {
    toggleAllRowsSelected(false);
    row.toggleRowSelected();
  }
```

You'll need to include `toggleAllRowsSelected` when destructuring the variables from useTable.

```
 const { toggleAllRowsSelected, selectedFlatRows,...} = useTable({ columns, data, ....}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do like this by my experience.

```
Cell: ({row}) => (
   <RadioButton
      {...row.getToggleRowSelectedProps({
         onChange: () => {
           const selected = row.isSelected; // get selected status of current row.
           toggleAllRowsSelected(false); // deselect all.
           row.toggleRowSelected(!selected); // reverse selected status of current row.
         },
      })}
   />
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tanstack table already has a prebuilt table option that handles that, which is `enableMultiRowSelection` and it can be used in 2 ways, either by:

- Passing a boolean value to either or not allow multiple row selection
- A function that given a row, returns whether to enable/disable multiple row selection for that row's children/grandchildren.

Here's an example of where I used the first use case of it:

```
const { table } = useCustomTable({
    multiRows: false,
    ...
});
```

From the snippet above, the `multiRows` variable was used to pass in the boolean function, then in my `useReactTable` props, I'm assigning the `enableMultiRowSelection` option the `multiRows` prop value as shown below:

```
function useCustomTable({ tableData, columns, multiRows=true }: ITableProps) {
const data = useMemo(() => tableData || [], [tableData]);

const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    enableMultiRowSelection: multiRows,
    ...
  });
  return { table };
}

export { useCustomTable };
```

You can read more from their official documentation: [Tanstack Table Options](https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/api/features/row-selection)

Answer (score 0):

I used a workaround to make this work, basically setting the selected rowId in the state.

```
const [selectedRowId, setSelectedRowId] = useState('0');

const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
    },
    usePagination
  );
```

This is a shortened version of the code for the table. As you can see it sets state whenever the user clicks on the row or checks the radio button.

```
<TableV2.Body {...getTableBodyProps()}>
            {rows.map((row) => {
              prepareRow(row);
              return (
                <TableV2.Row
                  key={row.id}
                  onClick={() => setSelectedRowId(row.id)}
                  {...row.getRowProps()}
                  bg={row.id !== selectedRowId ? 'white' : 'gray.10'}
                >
                  <TableV2.Cell key={`${row.id}-radio`}>
                    <Box testIds={{test: 'sku-detail-radio-button'}} mt={-12}>
                      <RadioButton
                        value={row.id}
                        checked={row.id === selectedRowId}
                        onChange={() => setSelectedRowId(row.id)}
                      />
                    </Box>
                  </TableV2.Cell>
```

If you want to pass the `selectedRowId` to the parent component, you can use `useEffect`:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        props.onRowSelection(selectedRowId);
      }, [props, selectedRowId]);
```

Comment: Hi there mate, appreciate the response but I just wanted you to know that I also managed to pull it of, and I think my way is much more simpler than that one.
Let me know if you want me to share it

Comment: @Àtishking oh nice! please share